# Location Manager causes "server did not accept client registration" warning

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone. When I am dealing with location manager I got the first message to access my location

Allow and Don't Allow if I press allow then it works fine.

But I press Don't Allow then it gives me the warning which I have displayed below :

```
Function,"void CLClientHandleDaemonDataRegistration(__CLClient*, mach_port_t, const CLDaemonCommToClientRegistration*, const __CFDictionary*)",server did not accept client registration 1
```

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Seems to me as if it works like defined. The has to allow access and this is good or did I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution, if the user does not allow your app to use the location service there is no way to enforce it.
You can check if you may use the location service:

```
BOOL result = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];

if (result) {
    dbgPrint(@"Location services enabeld");
} else  {
    dbgPrint(@"Location services disabeld");
}
```

Comment: How can we avoid that warning message displayed on the console screen.

Comment: You should check if the [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] returns true before creating an instance of the CLLocationManager.